# Traversing through array not working

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-5.5

The json object coming as a output in the variable $results like

```
           Array ( [ts] => MongoTimestamp Object ( [sec] => 1497334764 [inc] => 1 ) [t] => MongoInt64 Object ( [value] => 1 ) [h] => MongoInt64 Object ( [value] => -3885623284897060533 ) [v] => 2 [op] => i [ns] => mgl.triggersTbl [o] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 593f83ec1d7859cc0f000029 ) [Name] => Ahmad [Address] => Delhi ) ) 
           Array ( [ts] => MongoTimestamp Object ( [sec] => 1497349628 [inc] => 1 ) [t] => MongoInt64 Object ( [value] => 8 ) [h] => MongoInt64 Object ( [value] => -3083419979530819825 ) [v] => 2 [op] => i [ns] => mgl.triggersTbl [o] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 593fbdfc1d78591819000029 ) [Name] => Nehal [Address] => Mumbai ) ) 
           Array ( [ts] => MongoTimestamp Object ( [sec] => 1497428148 [inc] => 1 ) [t] => MongoInt64 Object ( [value] => 9 ) [h] => MongoInt64 Object ( [value] => -660915868390613413 ) [v] => 2 [op] => i [ns] => mgl.triggersTbl [o] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5940f0b41d78591414000029 ) [Name] => Seema [Address] => Mumbai ) )
```

The code is

```
             $cursor = $c->find(array('ns'=> 'mgl.triggersTbl', 'op' => 'i'));
    // $cursor->timeout(-1);
     $cursor->tailable(true);
     //$cursor->awaitData(true);

     while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
     $cursor->timeout(-1);
     try
     {
         $results =array();
         $results = $cursor->getNext();
         var_dump($results);
     }
```

Now I am trying to fetch these values one by one in order to make it presentable.

```
        foreach ($results as $key)
        {   
          foreach ($key as $p => $res)
           {
            echo "Timestamp"." : ". $key["sec"]."<br/>";
            echo "Name"." :".$res["Name"]."<br/>";
            echo "Address"." :".$res["Address"];
          }
        }
```

This code does not work. It throws error message.

" Cannot use object of type MongoTimestamp as array in " echo "Timestamp"." : ". $key["sec"]."
";"

If I use

```
        foreach ($results as $res)
        {   
            echo "Name"." :".$res["Name"]."<br/>";
            echo "Address"." :".$res["Address"];
        }
```

Still throws error message

Please help!!!

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Why two loops? Use `foreach ($results as $p => $res)`. Also usage of $key inside the inner loop seems strange.

Comment: It's array of object. you need to use `->` to access the property, not index.

Comment: I tried like   foreach ($results as $p => $res)
            {   
                echo "Name"." :".$res["Name"]."<br/>";
                echo "Address"." :".$res["Address"];
            }... It still throws that error message

Comment: can u show me how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every elements in the array is different so it makes no sense to loop through each of the elements in the array.

Assuming the below is `$results`,

```
array(7) { 
    ["ts"]=> object(MongoTimestamp)#6 (2) { 
        ["sec"]=> int(1497334764) 
        ["inc"]=> int(1)
    } 
    ["t"]=> object(MongoInt64)#7 (1) { 
        ["value"]=> string(1) "1"
    } 
    ["h"]=> object(MongoInt64)#8 (1) { 
        ["value"]=> string(20) "-3885623284897060533"
    }
    ["v"]=> int(2) 
    ["op"]=> string(1) "i"
    ["ns"]=> string(15) "mgl.triggersTbl"
    ["o"]=> array(3) {
        ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#9 (1) {
            ["$id"]=> string(24) "593f83ec1d7859cc0f000029"
        }
        ["Name"]=> string(5) "Ahmad"
        ["Address"]=> string(5) "Delhi"
    }
}
```

you can use codes below to print all values from top to bottom.

```
echo $results["ts"]->sec;
echo $results["ts"]->inc;
echo $results["t"]->value;
echo $results["h"]->value;
echo $results["v"];
echo $results["op"];
echo $results["o"]["_id"]->{'$id'};
echo $results["o"]["Name"];
echo $results["o"]["Address"];
```

Comment: I want this to be loop because there can be multiple similar json objects in $results array.

Comment: @Nida Please show us how exactly (what code) did you print out the `$results` variable dump.

Comment: @Nida They are of different arrays altogether? Please post the code you used to print those 3 arrays as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `foreach` for an array in this form, you iterate through the *values*, not the keys. And the first value is your object(MongoTimestamp), which you access as an array in the first `echo`. See the comments for additional suggestions.

**Update:** The array is kinda hard to read, maybe do a `print_r(array_keys($result))` to make sure that the structure is what you expect it to be (and not that something is nested a level deeper with arrays within your array).